# Phonegap 3.0 Custom Plugin

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I put together a plugin for an app some months ago with phonegap 2.7 and it worked perfectly. The plugin basically opens up the users phonebook and returns to my app the details of the contact the user selects.

I have recently upgraded to Phonegap 3.0 and I am trying to convert my plugin to 3.0; However I can't get the plugin to work now that it's all 3.0....here is what I have

**ContactView.java**

src\com\huronasolutions\plugins\ContactView.java

```
package com.huronasolutions.plugins;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;

public class ContactView extends CordovaPlugin {
    private static final int PICK_CONTACT = 1;
    private CallbackContext callback;

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        if (action.equals("getContact")) {

            this.callback = callbackContext;
            cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                    startContactActivity();
                    PluginResult mPlugin = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
                    mPlugin.setKeepCallback(true);
                    callbackContext.sendPluginResult(mPlugin);
                    }
            });
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void startContactActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
        this.cordova.startActivityForResult((CordovaPlugin) this, intent,
                PICK_CONTACT);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        String name = null;
        String number = null;
        String email = null;
        switch (reqCode) {
        case (PICK_CONTACT):
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c = this.cordova.getActivity().getContentResolver()
                        .query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String ContactID = c.getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String hasPhone = c
                            .getString(c
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

                    if (Integer.parseInt(hasPhone) == 1) {
                        Cursor phoneCursor = this.cordova
                                .getActivity()
                                .getContentResolver()
                                .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                        null,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                                + "='" + ContactID + "'", null,
                                        null);
                        while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                            number = phoneCursor
                                    .getString(phoneCursor
                                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        }
                    }
                    // get email address
                    Cursor emailCur = this.cordova
                            .getActivity()
                            .getContentResolver()
                            .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                                    null,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID
                                            + "='" + ContactID + "'", null,
                                    null);
                    while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
                        // This would allow you get several email addresses
                        // if the email addresses were stored in an array
                        email = emailCur
                                .getString(emailCur
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                        // String emailType = emailCur.getString(
                        // emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));
                    }
                    emailCur.close();

                    name = c.getString(c
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    JSONObject contactObject = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        contactObject.put("name", name);
                        contactObject.put("phone", number);
                        contactObject.put("email", email);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    callback.success(contactObject);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**ContactView.js**

\assets\www\js\android\ContactView.js

```
cordova.define("com.huronasolutions.plugins.ContactView", function (require, exports, module) {
    var exec = require("cordova/exec");

    var contactView = {
        show: function (successCallback, failCallback) {

            function success(args) {
                if (typeof successCallback === 'function')
                    successCallback(args);
            }

            function fail(args) {
                if (typeof failCallback === 'function')
                    failCallback(args);
            }

            return exec(
                function (args) { success(args); },
                function (args) { fail(args); },
                'ContactView',
                'getContact',
                []);
        }
    }
    module.exports = contactView;

});
```

I have the following in the head of my index.html file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/android/ContactView.js"></script>
```

When I call it in my code like this

```
window.contactView.show(
               function (contact) {
                   success({ "contact": contact, "msg": "success" });
               },
               function (fail) {
                   fail({ "msg": "We were unable to get the contact you selected." });
               }
           );
```

I get the following error in LogCat

> *09-17 22:09:24.285: E/Web Console(1679): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'show' of undefined at
>   file:///android_asset/www/js/txt2.js:477*

When I call it like this

```
 contactView.show(
                   function (contact) {
                       success({ "contact": contact, "msg": "success" });
                   },
                   function (fail) {
                       fail({ "msg": "We were unable to get the contact you selected." });
                   }
               );
```

LogCat says contactView is undefined.

Can someone help, I think I have followed every guide I can find online.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call your plugin like this:

```
cordova.require("com.huronasolutions.plugins.ContactView").show(
 function (contact) {
   success({ "contact": contact, "msg": "success" });
 },
 function (fail) {
   fail({ "msg": "We were unable to get the contact you selected." });
 }
);
```

Also make sure you have defined the plugin in your config.xml:

```
<feature name="contactView">
      <param name="android-package" value="com.huronasolutions.plugins.ContactView"/
</feature>
```

Comment: You are the MAN!!!!!!!!!!!! Thanks a million, this worked like a dream. So isn't there any shortcut way to do this, like to assign cordova.require("com.huronasolutions.plugins.ContactView") to a variable from within the plugin?

Comment: Cool, glad it worked :-) You should be able to shortcut it since cordova.require() returns an object instance, i.e. `window.contactView = cordova.require("com.huronasolutions.plugins.ContactView"); window.contactView.show(...);`

Comment: Can I do this from within the plugin? If yes, where would you recommend.

Comment: I have run into another issue which I should maybe make a different question but I thought I would ask you first, it seems the way messages are passed form the java to the javascript has changed in 3.0. When I select the contact from the address book the 'contact' object in function (contact) {
   success({ "contact": contact, "msg": "success" });
 }
 is "OK" not the JSONObject I pass to the callback from the java code. Any idea why and how I can get me data?

Comment: I figured it, I shouldn't have had callback.succes() in the execute method...thanks