# Issue with SMS cordova 3.5 plugin for android?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I have installed the [SMS plugin](https://github.com/aharris88/phonegap-sms-plugin) via CLI, and the installation was done properly. Then I wrote JavaScript code as follows:

```
function sendsms()
{
    alert("click");
    var number = $("#numberTxt").val();
    var message = $("#messageTxt").val();
    var intent = ""; //leave empty for sending sms using default intent
    var success = function() { alert('Message sent successfully'); };
    var error = function(e) { alert('Message Failed:' + e); };
    sms.send(number, message, intent, success, error);
}
```

HTML code:

```
<input name="" id="numberTxt" placeholder="Enter mobile number" value="" type="tel" />
<br/>
<textarea name="" id="messageTxt" placeholder="Enter message"></textarea>
<br/>
<input type="submit" onClick='sendsms()' value="Send SMS" >
```

After clicking "Send SMS" I get an alert "click", but the message isn't sent and also I don't get any response - whether sms is sent or not.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Will 'alert' work if you place it right before 'sms.send'?

Comment: No I didn't get the alert if I place alert right before sms.send(). What was the issue now? Can you suggest me something

Comment: Did you include jQuery library to your page?

Comment: Thanks a lot and lot. It is working after adding the jquery library

Comment: You're welcome. Or, if you don't want to use jQuery, you can replace  `$("#numberTxt").val()`  with  `document.getElementById("numberTxt").value`, and same with `messageTxt`.

Comment: You should also try setting up remote debugging so that you can see javascript errors in the console. You can set it up with Android using Chrome: http://adamwadeharris.com/remote-debugging-in-phonegap-with-chrome-devtools/ or with iOS, you can use Safari.